# grunt: Watch and synchronize files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want to run a local sync daemon.

It should watch `src` directory and copy any changed file to `dst` directory. There are many subdirectories in `src`, so the relative paths should be preserved. All necessary subdirectories in `dst` are already created.

I want to **filter** for `*.js` files only.

I've found a [grunt-sync](https://github.com/tomusdrw/grunt-sync) tool. The documentation is so short that I even don't know if it fits me. Here's my `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        sync: {
          main: {
            files: [{
                cwd: src,
                src: ['**/*.js'],
                dest: dst
            }]
          }
        }    
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'sync');

};
```

When I run grunt, I see no watch task. Grunt freezes for several seconds, then copies all files and exits. And I want a watch-sync daemon.

Comment: Node.js already has that built in -> http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: @adeneo: What if I write my first module to do this? :P

Comment: You're not using the watch module: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch ..., which would be necessary for it to actually monitor the folder constantly.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I know about the watch module existence, but I could not realize how to copy the single file that has changed

Comment: Have the "watch" call the "sync"?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I can't make "grunt-sync" copy the single changed file. It can copy everything only. I've forked one project https://github.com/mybodya/grunt-contrib-livecopy to create something better.
I have a feeling that nobody has coded anything like this before, so I will be the first? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16549622/139361

Comment: Odd that it copies more than the changed file as it's description would lead one to believe that the only reason it was created was to solve this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

I created a tool called duplicate which will do what you want (though a year later), it copies all matching files when start, and keep watching if there would be any changes.

It's not written as a Gulp or Grunt plugin because it doesn't need to be, but of course you may easily run it in a Gulp or Grunt task.

Check out https://github.com/vilic/duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but..  I had the same question. What I´ve done is to combine both tools.. grunt-sync and grunt-contrib-watch..

module.exports = function (grunt) {

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sync: {
      main: {
        files: [{
            cwd: src,
            src: ['**/*.js'],
            dest: dst
        }]
      }
    },
    watch: {
       jsxfiles: {
       files: ['**/*.js'],
       tasks: ['sync:main'],
     } //this means that when any of the pattern files changes, the sync task will be run...
     }  
 });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch'); //run the watch task isntead of just the sync once..
```

};

I hope this is helpful

KR Jon